# how to determine the equation of a hyperplane (W and b) using only support vectors points without a Lagrange multiplier?

Tags: machine-learning, mathematical-statistics, svm, geometry

In n-dimensional, assuming I have support vectors points (number of sv < n), can I find the hyperplan equation (w and b) that separates 2 sets of data using only support vectors points without a Lagrange multiplier.